# Batch run commands in child command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have the following in a batch file that needs to be run via Windows Task Scheduler. This is an example script.

```
@echo off
echo This is parent command prompt
<some external executable with some arguments>   & REM This launches another command prompt with special environment variables set

REM I want the following command to be run in the command prompt that got launched above
echo This is child command prompt
```

How do I run the last commands mentioned above in the command prompt that got launched?

OR

I launch the child command prompt independently that keeps running. Put the commands to be run in that command prompt in a batch file. Write some more batch code that somehow identifies that child command prompt and executes the commands in that child command prompt. Not sure how to do this either.

Following is a cooked up simple example to show what I mean

```
@echo off
echo This is parent command prompt
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "echo hello" & REM This launches another command prompt

REM I want the following commands to be run in the command prompt that got launched above
echo This is child command prompt
```

Comment: How about you provide us with real information, in order that we can replicate your specific issue, _`<some external executable with some arguments>` and `<some command specific to the child command prompt>` is not specific enough for us to assist you with any degree of certainty_. I'm going to assume that your secret external executable is launching a cmd.exe window, because of how you're invoking it. That information is therefore the most vital you can provide us with regarding your issue.

Comment: @Compo I have added a simple example as giving the secret executable is meaningless as it is not available to the world.

Comment: BTW your 'simple' example isn't valid code, _and is therefore not as simple as you thought!_ We need to understand exactly how you're running the scheduled task, and under what criteria, as well as have an explanation of exactly what you're trying to achieve, with a real world example showing what is actually happening and what the intent is. At present you're asking a general programming question on a site dedicated to helping with a single specific issue with your provided code.

Comment: Given your now modified simple example, the following single line batch file invoked from Windows Task Scheduler: `@Echo This is parent command prompt&(Start "Child Command Prompt" "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /D/Q/K "Echo hello&Echo This is child command prompt")&Pause`, will achieve exactly what you've asked. Does it answer your question? or was your example not representative of your real world task?

Comment: Right after "Or" in the post I'm lost. Can you clarify the question? It sounds like you just need some simple "GOTO" routines, or just do a "Call" on your other bat file.

Comment: @Compo Unfortunately it doesn't work in my scenario. I guess the simple example code is not representative. In your example I do not get where to insert the call to the proprietary executable i.e. `<some external executable with some arguments>`

Comment: @shadoe2020 What I want to do via scheduler is, launch the command prompt via the proprietary exe and then run some commands in that command prompt. This can be done in two ways. 1. Script that does the whole job, i.e. launches the command prompt (via proprietary exe) and runs the commands in them. OR 2. Script that does partial job, i.e. I launch the command prompt (via proprietary exe) manually and keep it open. Script just runs the commands in that already running command prompt.

Comment: @ontherocks, you provided the criteria, I provided what you required. Your commands for the child command prompt were inside the doublequotes, `echo hello`, my comment did exactly the same with an `Echo hello` then adding a second command between those doublequotes, _another `echo` command_, `Echo This is child command prompt`, (simply change that to your chosen command). I cannot help you further with that because this is a two way process; we can only help you if you help us. _You're disinterested in providing a real world command or an actual problem, which is what this site is for._

Comment: As a secondary note @ontherocks, you said, "I do not get where to insert the call to the proprietary executable". Please note that `Call` is used for batch files or batch file labels, not for executables.